# What type of shock would you call it when approaching around age 40 you see people all around you start taking regular medication

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

What type of shock is it called when you approach around age 40 and you see known people all around in last 30s start taking regular medication and you start thinking/fearing this will be a regular for you too sooner or later.

Comment: I'd call it 'a first intimation of mortality', but I can't find a snappy definition of the phrase anywhere.

Comment: @Spagirl +1. A *reality check*, perhaps, but (ironically) that doesn't go far enough.

Comment: It's called "getting old".  Or, "Your warranty has expired."

Comment: I am not sure if this is a question about English or psychology.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a **mid-life crisis**.

> A midlife crisis is a transition of identity and self-confidence that can occur in middle aged individuals, typically 45–64 years old.
>
> The phenomenon is described as a **psychological crisis brought about by events that highlight a person's growing age, inevitable mortality, and possibly shortcomings of accomplishments in life.** This may produce feelings of depression, remorse, and anxiety, or the desire to achieve youthfulness or make drastic changes to current lifestyle.
> The term was coined by Elliott Jaques in 1965. [...]
>
> - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midlife_crisis

Comment: Does this encompass anticipation of aging Parent's death too?

Comment: Good attempt, but might it possibly be somewhat overstating things?

Comment: @AMN I think that's different issue- but I'm not a psychologist!